# Find row number of matching value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying several different methods of finding the row number of `bingo` (listed and separated by asterisks) but none seem to work. What am I doing wrong? In all instances I've tried looking both for Bingo and "Bingo".

```
Sub Find_Bingo()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "Bingo"

    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
    Else
        MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
    End If

'************

    With Sheet1
        Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:=Bingo, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
 LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ 
 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End With

'************

Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("E").Find(Bingo, _
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2), LookIn:=xlValue, lookat:=xlWhole)

'************

FoundCell = Range("A:M").Find(Bingo)

'************

FoundCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Bingo, Range("A1:A200"), 0)

'************

FoundCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(Bingo).Row

'************

Range("A:A").Find(Bingo, Range("A1")).Row

'************

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(Bingo).Select

'************
End Sub
```

Comment: ws.Range("A:A") -> Still nothing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For your first method change `ws.Range("A")` to `ws.Range("A:A")` which will search the entirety of column a, like so:

```
Sub Find_Bingo()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim FoundCell As Range
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

            Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "Bingo"

            Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
            Else
                MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
            End If
End Sub
```

For your second method, you are using `Bingo` as a variable instead of a string literal.  This is a good example of why I add `Option Explicit` to the top of all of my code modules, as when you try to run the code it will direct you to this "variable" which is undefined and not intended to be a variable at all.

Additionally, when you are using `With...End With` you need a period `.` before you reference `Cells`, so `Cells` should be `.Cells`.  This mimics the normal qualifying behavior (i.e. Sheet1.Cells.Find..)

Change `Bingo` to `"Bingo"` and change `Cells` to `.Cells`

```
With Sheet1
        Set FoundCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Bingo", After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & FoundCell.Row)
Else
        MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
End If
```

### Update

In my

```
With Sheet1
    .....
End With
```

The `Sheet1` refers to a worksheet's code name, not the name of the worksheet itself.  For example, say I open a new blank Excel workbook.  The default worksheet is just `Sheet1`.  I can refer to that in code either with the code name of `Sheet1` or I can refer to it with the index of `Sheets("Sheet1")`.  The advantage to using a codename is that it does not change if you change the name of the worksheet.

Continuing this example, let's say I renamed `Sheet1` to `Data`.  Using `Sheet1` would continue to work, as the code name doesn't change, but now using `Sheets("Sheet1")` would return an error and that syntax must be updated to the new name of the sheet, so it would need to be `Sheets("Data")`.

In the VB Editor you would see something like this:

[image: code object explorer example]

Notice how, even though I changed the name to `Data`, there is still a `Sheet1` to the left.  That is what I mean by codename.

The `Data` worksheet can be referenced in two ways:

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.Name
Debug.Print Sheets("Data").Name
```

Both should return `Data`

More discussion on worksheet code names can be found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm).

Comment: Bingo! it actually worked. Thank you so very much Mr. Soulfire.

Comment: On which line of which code sample?  Both ran on my machine in Excel 2013.

Comment: Actually, it worked fine on a test page, but failed again on my main file. The problem was as I found out that I had to start the segment like so `with Sheets("Sheet1")`. Do you know what might be the cause of it? Learning how to avoid such syntax errors might be very useful.

Comment: Ah yes, I will update my answer to show you why there was a syntax error.

Comment: I see now. Thank you so much for taking the time and giving this thorough explanation! Now it's pretty clear how that will be useful.