# Finding the last row within a Specific Range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with finding the last row in a worksheet range.

For example:

Worksheet name is MyWorksheet

Range is A1:A200

What im trying to find out is the row number of the last cell that has data in the MyWorksheet range A1:A200.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: Will it always be a one column range?

Answer (score 0):

Define your Range, Set it and use .Find

Here is a good example of what you are trying to accomplish.

[Excel VBA Find row number of matching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190029/excel-vba-find-row-number-of-matching-value)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Reese, the problem is that the range is relative to a specific tab. For example: I have an October, November and December Tab. If I define a range for say October, and I run the vba macro on November, the named range will not apply to November. I need vba to identify a particular sheet based on a specific range, and get the last row within the range A1:A200.

Comment: So you are trying to loop through each tab and find the last cell that has value?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the last row within a range of a specific tab. For example: Sheets("DumpTab").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row. This works fine to get the last row from a specific column; but what about if I wanted a specific range of data (A1:A200) and get the row number of the last cell with data.

Comment: You set the Range in that column. for example: WorkSheet.Range("A:A") then use the Range you defined to find what youre looking for in that column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650508/excel-vba-find-last-row-in-range

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account all possible data layouts, inside and outside the range of interest requires consideration of a number of factors

- In general, the range of interest may be of any size, anywhere on the sheet
- There may be data adjacent to the range of interest, either above or below
- The range of interest may be entirely empty
- Is the "Last Row Number" required relative to the Range of Interest, or the Sheet
- Note: this code treats cells containing an empty string as containing data

---

```
Function RangeLastRow(r As Range, _
  Optional Col = 1, _
  Optional RelativeToSheet As Boolean = False) As Long

    Dim rw As Long
    With r.Cells(r.Rows.Count, Col)
        If IsEmpty(.Value2) Then
            rw = .End(xlUp).Row
            If rw < r.Row Then
                rw = r.Row
            End If
        Else
            rw = r.Row + r.Rows.Count - 1
        End If
    End With
    If IsEmpty(r.Cells(rw - r.Row + 1, Col)) Then
        ' range is empty
        rw = 0
    Else
        If Not RelativeToSheet Then
            rw = rw - r.Row + 1
        End If
    End If
    RangeLastRow = rw
End Function
```

Use it as a UDF on a sheet, or in VBA like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Using default Column 1 and Relative to Sheet
    MsgBox RangeLastRow(Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("A1:A200"))
End Sub
```